# On whether an integral of indicator functions is equal to zero.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Take

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \int_{S^1} 1_B(x) 1_B(x+t \omega ) d \sigma(\omega) dx , \tag{1}$$

where $B \subset [-1,1]^2$, $1_B$ are indicator functions, $0<t \le 1$, and $d \sigma$ is the surface measure on the unit circle $S^1$.

Does the double integral in $(1)$ vanish if there are no points $x,y \in B$ such that $|x-y | = t$ ?